# Hiding subsequent divs when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I have a series of divs that have radio buttons and a "next" button that designates where the form goes from there.

Right now, the next button is a "plus" button and the back button is a "minus" button.  The "minus" button is functional in hiding the div it is attached to but not the subsequent divs.  How do I work it so that the rest of the form is hidden when the user selects the "minus" button?

I'm only including one of the functions which includes only a couple of the divs, but assuming they go from 0-11. This one should hide 1-11 if the minus button is clicked.

```
var image = document.getElementById("plus");

function changeSign(id) {
    var image = document.getElementById(id);

    if (image.getAttribute('src') == "image/plus_btn.png") {
        image.src = "image/minus_btn.png";
        console.log("Showing");
    } else {
        image.src = "image/plus_btn.png";
    }
}

function show1(id) {
    changeSign(id);
    var image = document.getElementById(id);
    if (image.getAttribute('src') == "image/plus_btn.png") {
        console.log("hiding")
        document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('div11').style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        if (document.querySelector('input#div0symp').checked) {
            console.log("div1");
            document.getElementById('div11').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'block';
        }
        if (document.querySelector('input#div0asymp').checked) {
            console.log("div11")
            document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('div11').style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hiding Bug**

```
for(a = 1; a <= 11; a++){
    document.getElementById('div'+ a).style.display = 'none';
}
```

You can query by class name to get the array length, such as el = document.getElementByClassName("className"); and then use el.length

If you do use this method make sure a runs from 0 to < el.length
Also alter the 'div'+ a to 'div'+ (a + 1) to make sure it still refers DIV id 1-11 and not 0-10